# Bash script for inotifywait - How to write deletes to log file, and cp close_writes?

Tags: bash, inotify

I have this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash


inotifywait -m -e close_write --exclude '\*.sw??$' . |
#adding --format %f does not work for some reason
while read dir ev file; do
        cp ./"$file" zinot/"$file"
done
~
```

Now, how would I have it do the same thing but also handle deletes by writing the filenames to a log file?
Something like?

```
#!/bin/bash


inotifywait -m -e close_write --exclude '\*.sw??$' . |
#adding --format %f does not work for some reason
while read dir ev file; do
        # if DELETE, append $file to /inotify.log
        # else
        cp ./"$file" zinot/"$file"
done
~
```

EDIT:

By looking at the messages generated, I found that inotifywait generates `CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE` whenever a file is closed. So that is what I'm now checking in my code.
I tried also checking for `DELETE`, but for some reason that section of the code is not working. Check it out:

```
#!/bin/bash

fromdir=/path/to/directory/
inotifywait -m -e close_write,delete --exclude '\*.sw??$' "$fromdir" |
while read dir ev file; do
        if [ "$ev" == 'CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE' ]
        then
                # copy entire file to /root/zinot/ - WORKS!
                cp "$fromdir""$file" /root/zinot/"$file"
        elif [ "$ev" == 'DELETE' ]
        then
                # trying this without echo does not work, but with echo it does!
                echo "$file" >> /root/zinot.txt
        else
                # never saw this error message pop up, which makes sense.
                echo Could not perform action on "$ev"
        fi

done
```

In the dir, I do `touch zzzhey.txt`. File is copied. I do `vim zzzhey.txt` and file changes are copied. I do `rm zzzhey.txt` and the filename is added to my log file `zinot.txt`. Awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `-e delete` to your monitor, otherwise `DELETE` events won't be passed to the loop. Then add a conditional to the loop that handles the events. Something like this should do:

```
#!/bin/bash

inotifywait -m -e delete -e close_write --exclude '\*.sw??$' . |
while read dir ev file; do
  if [ "$ev" = "DELETE" ]; then
    echo "$file" >> /inotify.log
  else
    cp ./"$file" zinot/"$file"
  fi
done
```

Comment: How do you execute this. Do you send this script process into background?

Comment: @Codex73 You execute it like you execute any other script, and you send it to the background if you want it to run in the background, like any other script.